# Multiple users simultaneously updating XML file

Tags: xml, database, ms-access

Let's say you got the following scenario:

An application runs locally on two computers, the XML file is shared.

User 1: load the file.
User 2: load the file, update row 5.
User 1: update row 6, click "Save".
User 2: click "Save".

Can i prevent from last "Save" click override the updated values of user 1?

Will MS Access DB instead of XML file solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access might partially solve them, it's weaker in this area than a full dbms.
if you want to stay file based, then you have three basic options.

you write a "server" that deals with concurrent access to the file.

you use a pessimistic lock, first person to ask to edit the file gets it, others are read only

you use an optimistic lock.
if the file has changed since it was loaded, then don't allow it to be saved. You can then beef that up  by doing diff and conflict resolution. Think merging code changes, that will get complicated quick though.

NB even with a dbms you might need a conflict resolution layer.

Comment: Can you elaborate why Access will partially solve it? I'm talking about a desktop app installed locally on 10-15 PCs and the .mdb file will be stored on a shared drive.

Comment: Mdb file is stored on a shared drive. Each client accesses it, But for one or three brave attempts at dealing with collisions, not that much different to what you have now. It's better solution, but a full dbms (access is a desktop) would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Any decent database will solve concurrency problems such as this. This is why people use MySQL/SQL Server/Oracle/PostGre etc. instead of text files for storing data (like the posts in StackOverflow, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Access will sort of solve the problem, as you will then only have locking at record level, rather than file (or table) level.

I would consider using a more client/server database as access is a file-based rdbms, and does not cope well with concurrency at 10-15 users, increasing the number of users will scale really badly.

MySQL is a good start, and free too :)